# Calling Java method from C++ using JNI, android

Tags: java, android, c++, methods, java-native-interface

This is my code for ImageTargets.java

```
package com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets;

public void changeIsDisplayed()
    {
        if(isDisplayed)
            isDisplayed = false;
        else
        {
            isDisplayed = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call changeIsDisplayed from ImageTargets.cpp from this code:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargetsRenderer_renderFrame(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass javaClass = env->FindClass("com/qualcomm/QCARSamples/ImageTargets/ImageTargets");
     jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(javaClass, "changeIsDisplayed", "()V");
     env->CallVoidMethod(obj,method);
}
```

But it keeps crashing, and says there is a fatal jni error. I cannot seem to figure it out. Is this the best method for calling a java function from C++?

EDIT: The error is 
6347-6734/com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1231

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of information and late reply. I seem to be having a hard time with error checking since this is through android which gives me a harder time to Log it. I hope you understand.

EDIT: Upon error checking it crashes on the line of FindClass method. Any ideas?

Comment: _"it keeps crashing, and says there is a fatal jni error"_ What is the full, exact error message?

Comment: 6347-6734/com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1231
So far that is what is coming out. I do not understand the error number.

Comment: give more code and more log please. edit the question.

Comment: And from where in your C++ code are you calling `FindClass`? Are you sure that the correct classloader is used at that point? You really ought to add error checking for all your JNI calls.

Comment: What is your `obj`? You should provide the enough code to show what's you're exactly doing.

Comment: Add checks for javaClass == NULL and method == NULL to see if that's the problem. Also you can write your Java code in more compact form as isDisplayed = !isDisplayed;

Comment: @Michael What do you mean by correct classloader? I'm sorry. This is really my first time using JNI.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's crashing for you, but instead of doing `FindClass()`, you might try doing `jclass javaClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj)`.